# NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionInterceptor.<init>(Lorg/springframework/core/task/AsyncTaskExecutor;)V exception

Tags: java, spring

I got this error when I try to deploy my Spring project to tomcat server inside a docker container.

```
[main] ERROR org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader  - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAsyncAnnotationProcessor': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionInterceptor.<init>(Lorg/springframework/core/task/AsyncTaskExecutor;)V
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1455)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:728)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:449)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:388)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:293)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4643)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5109)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:718)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:703)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1141)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1876)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectories(HostConfig.java:1053)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:428)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1585)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:308)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:424)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:367)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:966)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:839)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1427)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1417)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:943)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:258)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:770)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:682)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:350)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:492)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionInterceptor.<init>(Lorg/springframework/core/task/AsyncTaskExecutor;)V
    at org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.AsyncAnnotationAdvisor.buildAdvice(AsyncAnnotationAdvisor.java:121)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.AsyncAnnotationAdvisor.<init>(AsyncAnnotationAdvisor.java:82)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.AsyncAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.afterPropertiesSet(AsyncAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:100)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
    ... 52 more
```

Note that I am using these version for Spring:

```
<springframework.security.version>3.1.0.RELEASE</springframework.security.version>
<springframework.version>3.1.4.RELEASE</springframework.version>
```

Previously I use Tomcat 6 + JDK 6 + Spring 3.1.1 work perfectly then I switch to Tomcat 9 + JDK 8 + Spring 3.1.4 and I got this error. I think 3.1.4 somehow did not work correctly with JDK 8. Any ideas would be more than helpful.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Spring Security 3.1.0.RELEASE requires Spring Framework 3.0.6.RELEASE. Since you are using Spring Framework 3.1.4.RELEASE you might experience problems like the `NoSuchMethodError`.

You can see the version in the [spring-security-core-3.1.0.RELEASE.pom](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/security/spring-security-core/3.1.0.RELEASE/spring-security-core-3.1.0.RELEASE.pom):

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.6.RELEASE</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
```

Comment: I use Spring Security 3.1.0 with Spring Framework 3.1.1 work without problem. But I change to JDK 8 so I need to change to Spring Framework 3.1.4 in order to work.

Comment: @ThongVo you are overriding the compile time dependencies of Spring Security. You can test after each such change but the results will vary. The right thing to do is to use Spring Framework 3.0.6.RELEASE or upgrade Spring Security to a version that is using 3.1.4.RELEASE.